# Convert hex string to string of characters using stringstream c++

Tags: c++

I have hex string call sumString = "20 54 48 41 4e 4b 09 79 6f 75 09" I want to convert the string of ascii characters. Here is my code:

```
string sub;
std::stringstream ss;
int dec;
char ch;
for(size_t t = 0; t < sumString.size(); t++){
    ss << sumString;
    ss >> hex >> dec;
    ch = (char)dec;
    sub += ch;
}
cout << "substring = \"" << sub << "\"\n";
```

The output is " THANK   you  THANK  you  THANK  you "
I don't know why it print out three times. Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Can't you convert the whole string at once?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I tried to put the conversion outside the loop and it gives me an empty substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in your thinking, you just missed a bit in making the conversion. The `std::stoi` conversion is all you need -- but with a twist. Since it would normally return an `integer`, you must explicitly cast to `char` in order to produce ASCII output.

Further, I suspect the point of the exercise was to investigate the parameters that change the behavior of `std::stoi` (e.g. `stoi (string, pos, base)` where base would be `16` in your case)

Putting that together, does change things a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define NBASE 16

int main (void) {

    std::string sumString = "20 54 48 41 4e 4b 09 79 6f 75 09", hex;
    std::stringstream s (sumString);
    while (s >> hex)
        std::cout << (char)std::stoi(hex, 0, NBASE);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexstr2ascii
 THANK  you
```

Without the base specified, you get a completely different (though innocuous looking answer), e.g.

```
        std::cout << (char)std::stoi(hex);
```

**Subtly Incorrect Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexstr2ascii
60)     OK
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I also tried your approaching, but the compiler complains that there is  no matching function for call to 'stoi' even though I already has std.

Comment: Yes, it caught me too until I looked at the original string and wondered "Where the hell did the `space` go?". Then I snapped to the base conversion issue. Good luck with your coding `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Output is actually " THANK you THANK you THANK you T".

Well, `ss << sumString;` inside the loop puts `sumString` into `ss` 32 times. Then you are reading `dec` trom that repeating stream 32 times. That is how you get a triple "THANK you".

Try something like this

```
string sub;
std::stringstream ss;
int dec;
char ch;
ss << sumString;    
for (size_t t = 0; !ss.eof(); t++) {
    ss >> hex >> dec;
    ch = (char)dec;
    sub += ch;
}
cout << "substring = \"" << sub << "\"\n";
```

Comment: I would use `std::istringstream` with a `while` loop instead: `string sub; std::istringstream iss(sumString); int dec; while (iss >> hex >> dec) { sub += (char)dec; } cout << "substring = \"" << sub << "\"\n";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for input. Sure that would be more readable, but my intent was to make as minimal changes to original code as possible to show where is the real problem.